# Brackets containing a datatype on right hand side of assignment operator

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list, implicit-conversion, void-pointers

I'm trying to understand why I sometimes see brackets containing a data type on the right hand side of an assignment operator in C.

Specifically I was trying to implement a linked list and because I'm still new to C I was using [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_program_in_c.htm) to guide me.

I came across this line: `struct node* link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

It's part of the `instertFirst` function which, I guess, adds a new item to the head of the linked list.

Breaking this line down according to my current understanding it states: create a `struct node` pointer called `link` that points to a newly allocated chunk of memory that is the size of the `node` struct.

What exactly then is the purpose of `(struct node*)` ? My best guess is that it gives that newly allocated chunk of memory a type...?

Comment: That's a typecast.

Comment: It's redundant with `malloc()` because it returns `void *`, which can be converted to any other pointer type without casting. But in general, `(typename)` converts values from one type to another.

Comment: Related: [What exactly is a type cast in C/C++?](/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `malloc` returns a pointer of the type `void *` independent on for which object the memory is allocated.

In C a pointer of the type `void *` may be assigned to a pointer of any other object type.

So you could write

```
struct node* link = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

In C++ such an implicit conversion is prohibited. You need explicitly to cast the returned pointer of the type `void *` to the type `struct node *` like

```
struct node* link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

In C as it was mentioned above such a casting is redundant and sometimes only used for self-documenting of the code.